# How to select the relation between column SQL

Tags: sql

Table1

[image]

How do I select all relation using value 5 as variable.

I need result to return value as below
Result

[image]

Below is sample that i have dont but i unable to get all relation :

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE AS VARCHAR(200) = 5
SELECT [ID1] FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID2 = @VARIABLE OR ID2 IN (SELECT [ID1] FROM [TABLE] WHERE ID2 = @VARIABLE )
```

Comment: Please have a look at the ["how to ask a question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Then please come back and update your question with the missing information, one of the most important of which is showing us what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry for my lack information, What i needed is i have bunch of record and that 1,2,3,4,5 is one batch.....i want filter based on no 5 and display all record as per second picture....i just cannot imagine proper way to do it.

Comment: For example 
1. From the table I want select item filter by no 5 and return no 4
2. Since no 4 is related to No 3 that mean I will have result 3 and 2
3. then 2 also related to no 1, then I will get 1 also as relation
My main key is no 5, and whenever I change my key either 2 or 3 or 1 I will return same value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems this should do.

```
SELECT ID1 THEID FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT ID2 THEID FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: This way will return all record on the table,

Comment: Based on how you explained your question, this is how a normal person would think the solution would be. Could you edit your question and explain a little more clearly how exactly should that table showing 1,2,3,4,5 in the output be produced?

Comment: sorry about it, I add the sample code that I has done but its only return 3,4 I just want return as a table like my second picture

Comment: Do you want the chain to continue till the minimum possible number in the table? I see that through 5 in id2, you got to 4 in id1...then from 4 in id2, you got to 3 in id1....and so on? Is that correct interpretation?

Comment: yes yes like that one and if i add another row in id1=6 and id2=7 means no chain on it.. only select 1,2,3,4,5

Comment: Okay. When you get to 3, there is no 3 in `id2` column, should the query stop there? The output in that case would be 4,5.

Comment: Nope...still return same as I get 5, means two way filtering.. coz 3 got chain into 2 and 4 should return same

Comment: Or if you think this way is hard to interpret, can you give idea the best way should I manage my table, thus I can manipulate same idea on the table record

Comment: Even if it is two-way, you see there 3 is not present in id2 and 2 is not present in id1 which would break the chain. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Or when you say two-way, you mean first mapping IDs from id1 to id2 and getting all numbers(set1), then mapping IDs from id2 to id1 and getting all numbers(set2). Then combining both these sets. Would that be right?

Comment: Yup shuld be like that

Comment: Should the output change if instead of @Variable 5, you choose some other value, say 2?

Comment: Variable 5 is not fixed, it can be changes. and whenever I change I will get all chain for the variable. If I change to variable = 2, 2 chain to 3,1.3 chain to 2,4 4 chain to 5 i will have the the chain value.

Comment: Is it okay if there are temp tables? I am trying a method, may not be the best but does involve creating temporary tables and then using them in next steps.

Comment: Its ok as long as I can get the result.

Comment: I am sorry, man. I tried a lot. Can only come up with a static solution that won't work if you had more entries in the table.

Comment: owh..its ok.I just recreate my table design and apply another way.btw thanks for your reply

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use union operator like below

**eg1:**

```
select * from (
  select ID1 as theId from Tabel1
  union
  select ID2 as theId from Tabel1
  ) as T order by theId asc
```

**eg2 :**

```
With  T AS  (
   select ID1 as theId from Tabel1
   union
   select ID2 as theId from Tabel1 
)
select * from T order by theId
```

Comment: thank for your reply but how should I filter based on number 5 when use union